# Error 403 Forbidden al consumir API REST a través de un HTTP Proxy

Tags: java, api, rest, http, proxy

Buen día comunidad:
Tengo una aplicación Java y estoy intentando consumir un API REST, a través de un http Proxy, debido a que el servidor donde tengo instalado el jar no tiene salida a internet.

Este es mi código para llamar al API

```
URL endpointLoginAPI = new URL(this.properties.login_endpoint);
Proxy proxy = new Proxy(Proxy.Type.SOCKS , new InetSocketAddress(this.properties.proxy_ip,this.properties.proxy_port));
HttpURLConnection conn = (HttpURLConnection) endpointLoginAPI.openConnection(proxy);
String sessionid = null;
try {
    conn.setDoOutput(true);
    conn.setInstanceFollowRedirects(false);
    conn.setRequestMethod(this.properties.login_method);
    conn.setRequestProperty(this.properties.header_content_type_key, this.properties.header_content_type_value + ";" + this.properties.header_content_type_encoding);
    conn.setRequestProperty(this.properties.header_apikey_key, this.properties.header_apikey_value);
    conn.setRequestProperty("Accept", this.properties.header_content_type_encoding);
    conn.addRequestProperty("User-Agent", "Mozilla");
    conn.setUseCaches(false);
    String jsonRequest = utilService.generateRequest(processId, "login", null, null); //metodo interno para generar el JSON Request
    OutputStream os = conn.getOutputStream();
    try {
        byte[] input = jsonRequest.getBytes("utf-8");
        os.write(input, 0, input.length);
    } catch (IOException ioe){
        throw new Exception(ioe);
    } finally {
        os.close();
    }
    JsonObject myJson = getResponseFromAPI(processId, conn, "GETSESSIONID"); //Método interno para leer el response y parsearlo a un objeto JSON
    sessionid = myJson.get("session_id").toString();
} catch (Exception e){
    this.logger.error("[" + processId + "] ERROR GETSESSIONID: " + e.getMessage());
} finally {
    this.logger.info("[" + processId + "] OBTENIENDO EL SESSIONID - END");
    return sessionid;
}
```

Pero como respuesta del API, tengo un ERROR 403 Forbidden:

**ERROR AL INVOCAR EL API GETSESSIONID: Server returned HTTP response code: 403 for URL: https://hostname/api/v1/auth/login**

Quisiera saber si hay algo mal en el uso del HTTP_PROXY que hace que el API rechace la petición, o que alternativa podría usar para poder consumir el API desde este servidor sin salida a internet.

**PD1: Como dato, si ejecuto el mismo jar (sin usar el http_proxy) en un servidor B (que si tiene salida a internet), el API responde correctamente.**

**PD2: El JDK del servidor es 1.6.0_45**

Answer (score 0):

La información no es suficiente para dar respuesta, se tendría que diagnosticar primero si el proxy es del tipo correcto (HTTP, HTTPS, SOCKS4, SOCKS5), si requiere autenticación y si puede conectarse al servicio HTTP[S] remoto. Según la plataforma puede probarse el proxy con distintas herramientas. En un entorno tipo UNIX con cURL puede correrse la herramienta curl para realizar dicha prueba.

`curl --verbose --proxy socks5h://<proxy_ip>:<proxy_port> https://hostname/api/v1/nonexistent`

Dicha petición debería resultar en una respuesta HTTP 404 si la conexión al servidor remoto a través del proxy pudo realizarse.

Comment: Gracias por la respuesta, acá los datos faltantes. El proxy es de tipo HTTP, no requiere autenticación y si logra conectarse al servicio remoto. El servidor desde donde ejecuto el jar es un RedHat Linux 7.2.
Hice la prueba con el CURL, y me sigue dando el resultado 403 Forbbiden.